# Fields applied to the User area are not translatable?

Tags: users, localization

I have a site which allows people to register as a member from the front end. I've got a bunch of fields attached to the User so that each person can build their own extended profile page; the site is bilingual. I've successfully got fields translatable when they're attached to a Section (the fields are marked as translatable), but when the same fields are attached to User there appears to be no way to input content in a different language; the familiar language switch in the back-end is not there... what am I missing?

E.g., here is the biography field, marked as translatable:

[image: translatable-field]

Here is the result when the field is used in a Section (note the interface has a language switch on the right, which can be toggled and the contents of the biography field changes):

[image: translatable-field-in-a-section]

But here is the same field when used in a User, note the lack of a way to change the language:

[image: translatable-field-in-a-user]

**Bonus Question:**
Assuming these fields are translatable; how would I get the front-end user form to list the fields in both English and Welsh so the user could fill in both on one page (i.e., without them needing to switch the site itself into another language)?

Comment: I miss this feature too. We have job descriptions shown in the frontend for authors (backend users) and they are not translatable. **+1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not missing anything; user content is currently not translatable. (It's up to each type of element whether it wants to support translatable content, and we felt that 99% of the time it would not be desirable for users to have translatable profiles.

Comment: Ah Ok, thanks, Brad Bell seemed to think they were already translatable, which is why I asked the question! Is this something on the 'to do' list for the near future?

Comment: PS: to clarify my use case; the site is an arts directory, listing self-registering artists who sell in the local area. The local area is bilingual so their profile pages (which have their sample art etc) need to also be bilingual.

Comment: It's possible that we add a setting for it, but no promises!

Comment: This Welsh case is probably a pretty good example of the usefulness, Brandon. When I lived nearby more than a decade ago, the intent to re-establish Welsh language was already strong. To get a job in teaching, government, etc., it was a very good idea if not required to show Welsh skills. The ability to tailor user content in both languages would be a boost to this, even if it is only in a resume for the user, such as User fields.

Comment: I miss this feature, too. Any news on that matter @BrandonKelly Have a site where people can register, too. The users are supposed to present themselves in their profiles in different languages.

Comment: @medoingthings you can add a  reaction to https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1058 to cast your vote for translatable user fields (and be notified of any updates).