# Custom fields on users

Tags: users

Is it possible somehow to add custom fields to the users in Craft?
I'd like the users to be able to add a Bio.

I know I can add a channel but wondering if I am missing something obvious or if this would be a good feature request?

I'd like to add, bio, social media info ect, about the author etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can. Go to **Settings** > **Users** then the **Fields** tab.

Here you can add fields just like you would for categories or entry types.

Comment: These fields are **not translatable**, though – regardless of how the field is set up. See here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/511